# How to fix weird Android Studio editor mode?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, editor

I played around with the android editor and noticed following:

[image: I can click whereever I want, and write.]

If I paste code with 5 lines, and 2 lines below where I want to paste it, it overrides everything below and does not create new lines for the pasted code. So how can I stop this unwanted behaviour?

Comment: Write code parts. Don't attach image for it

Comment: Did you activate the paste button on your keyboard?

Comment: Yes, I pasted the code with ctrl + v like everybody else.

Comment: Maybe you just activated "overwrite mode" (indicated by a rectangular cursor that overlaps a character) - the default is "insert mode" (indicated by a line cursor between characters). If this was the case you could just have pressed the "Insert" key to toggle back to "insert mode"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try resetting Studio Settings.

Go to this location in your pc `C:\Users\[Username]`

In this location, you have noticed a directory called `.AndroidStudio`

Delete it.

Now your android studio is totally reset.